# Values are not appending to currenthttp parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

While changing the text from select box values are updating to hidden fields but these values are not coming current http paramater .

eg:

```
$(document).on('change','.cart .quantitycolumn .quantityinput' ,function(){
   var qty = $(this).closest('.tablerow').find('.quantityinput option:selected').val();
   var uuid = $(this).closest('.tablerow').find('.quantityinput').data('uuid');
   var newUUID = $(this).closest('.tablerow').find('.quantityinput').data('newuuid');
   $('[name=quantityValue]').val(qty);
   $('[name=ParentUUID]').val(uuid);
   $('[name=newUUID]').val(newUUID);
});
```

Please give me hint how do we resolve this issue.

Thanks a lot!:)

Comment: Can you please say what are you getting and what you are expecting to get?

Comment: i am not getting anything i want respective values.

Comment: i am not getting values but values are updated in hidden fields.Please give me hint how to resolve this issue.Thanks